# ¿Como puedo traerme los ultimo 5 mensajes de un contacto en orden ascendente?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo esta lectura en el controlador

**controllers/mensajes_controller.rb**

```
@contacto = Contacto.includes(:mensajes).find_by(id: params[:id])
```

Tengo estos dos modelos, contactos y mensajes

**En models/mensajes:**

```
belongs_to :contacto
```

**en models/contactos:**

```
has_many :mensajes, -> { order(:id => :asc).limit(5) }, dependent: :destroy
```

Pero esto me trae los primeros 5 mensajes ordenados ascendentemente

**Probé con esto:**

```
has_many :mensajes, -> { order(:id => :desc).limit(5) }, dependent: :destroy
```

y me trajo los últimos 5 mensajes (lo que quiero) pero de manera descendente (lo que no quiero)
Me fui por la solución del **sort** del **hash**

```
@contacto.mensajes = @contacto.mensajes.sort # no funciona


Contacto_mensajes = @contacto.mensajes.sort # funciona pero pierdo la relación de contacto mensajes
```

Yo lo que real y únicamente necesito es que me traiga los últimos 5 mensajes pero ordenados de manera ascendente.

*¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo traer los últimos 5 mensajes ordenados ascendentemente por ID?*

O

*¿Cómo ordenar el hash @contacto.mensajes por ID ascendentemente de una manera sencilla?*

Comment: ¿y usar un [`reverse_each`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/reverse_each) con tu 2da opción?

Comment: sería genial, pero el detalle es que no uso el método each, me voy con un render @contacto.mensajes e invoco a una forma con el detalle de cada mensaje.

Comment: Ahhh dale, entonces prueba con `@contacto.mensajes.reverse`, aunque ojo que esto te convierte tu objeto resultante de `ActiveRecord_Relation` a `Array`

Comment: No hace nada amigo Alter Lagos

Comment: Que raro, porque antes de poner mi comentario anterior, probé en mi consola de rails con unos datos que tengo y funcionó, aunque apliqué el orden en la consola, no en la misma definición de la relación. Ahí [un pantallazo como prueba de mi resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgGtm.png). Podrías probar si efectivamente funciona en tu consola rails, porque quizás sea otro el problema.

Comment: Tal y como lo haces si funciona, pero eso es una lectura de un solo modelo directamente, lo que quiero es hacer una lectura por relación de uno a muchos y que el muchos me traiga  el máximo (limit) pero ordenado ascendentemente, lo que he logrado desde el primer momento es que me los traiga pero ordenados descendentemente.

Comment: Es que no hay una funcionalidad de active record (que yo conozca al menos) que te permita hacer lo que pides. Yo veo que la única parte donde podrías realizar lo que pides es cuando ya hayas traído tus mensajes y de ahí manipularlos para lo que deseas. De hecho, acabo de probar [en un render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajcm0.png) (que creo es lo que buscas) el mismo set de datos que te mostré ayer y funcionó sin problemas.

Comment: De hecho TODO el tiempo tuviste la razón amigo Alter Lagos, me senté con la mente totalmente en blanco y empecé de cero, solo para ver tu razonamiento (partiendo del hecho que a ti si te salía y a mi no), acto seguido, invoqué a la consola de rails `$ rails console`, solo para hacer exactamente lo que tu hiciste y lo pude ver todo, mi error, MI GRAN ERROR era QUERER poner el reverse en el controlador, y tal como lo tengo en la lógica, había que ponerlo en la vista `<%= render @contacto.mensajes.reverse %>`, ZAZ, funcionó!!!!!

Comment: Si, suele pasar de volver a un problema con la mente despejada, ve uno las cosas de otra perspectiva :) . He pasado los comentarios a una respuesta, para que puedas marcarla como correcta. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres iterar un elemento al revés, puedes usar un [`reverse_each`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/reverse_each) con tu 2da opción.
En caso de que quieras usar una colección ya invertida (por ejemplo, para pasarla como parámetro en `<%= render @contacto.mensajes %>`, puedes usar [`reverse`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/reverse).

Atención con la segunda opción, que te retornará una instancia de `Array` en vez de `ActiveRecord_Relation`, por lo que ya no tendrías acceso a [los métodos](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) de ésta.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no entiendo 100% tu pregunta.
Sin embargo, te dejo algo que quizá te sirva:

Para traer los **ÚLTIMOS 5** mensajes ordenados de manera **ASCENDENTE** por ID a partir de un scope en el modelo se puede hacer lo siguiente:

**Opción 1:**

```
has_many :mensajes, -> { order(:id => :asc).last(5) }, dependent: :destroy
```

OJO: Este método tiene un problema. Al hacer un `.last` la query de SQL trabaja con **TODOS** los mensajes (quizá existan millones). Por lo que este método yo lo descartaría. Puedes comprobarlo en tu log.

**Opción 2:**

Una mejora al código puede ser usando `offset` de la siguiente manera:

```
has_many :mensajes, -> { order(:id => :asc).offset(Mensaje.count - 5).limit(5) }, dependent: :destroy
```

Al ver la ejecución de esto por el log, mejora PERO:

`Mensaje.count` es lento por lo que también descartaría esta opción.

**Opción 3:**

A mi parecer (y sin entender mucho tu situación) creo que esta es la mejor opción.

```
has_many :mensajes, -> { order(:id => :desc).limit(5).reverse_order, dependent: :destroy
```

Cuéntame si te sirve.

Saludos!

Comment: `order(:id => :desc).reverse_order` es lo mismo que `order(:id => :asc)`

Comment: Si, como dice el amigo Alter Lagos es lo mismo, y al ponerle order(:id => :asc).reverse_order vuelvo al problema inicial, me trae los últimos 5 pero en modo descendente.

Comment: @rrg1459 Edité la respuesta. En vez de 
`order(:id => :desc).reverse_order.limit(5)` es `order(:id => :desc).limit(5).reverse_order`